# Ubuntu Phone - detect system type Desktop or Mobile

Tags: ubuntu-touch, programming, qt, qml, detect

Is there a way to detect platform from QML or Qt C++ classes? I have Qt/QML project supplied to Linux/Android/Windows at one time, I see it's possible to deploy it to Ubuntu Phone. Is there a way to detect that project runs on Mobile not Desktop Linux from QML or Qt? As I see I can't use preprocessor directives, can't find anything about this. Please help.

**In short**

How can I detect when my application deployed on Ubuntu Touch or to Desktop?

Answer (score -1):

I know about detecting the system using simple ping command:

```
TTL
64   Linux/BSD
128  Windows
255  UNIX
```

You can change the default TTL, but it is usually the default one.
Or try the nmap:

```
nmap -O
```

But you have to study these command (sources) to find the answer you need.

Comment: thanks, but this can't be used in compile time to deploy my application with correct parameters

Comment: I updated my question, basically I interested about both Linux'es but one is Ubuntu Desktop and another is Ubuntu Touch. I know how to detect system in C++